# ¿Es posible que el navegador de los usuarios web esté bloqueando la ejecución de javascript?

Tags: javascript, php, fetch

Resulta que he montado una div que hace de "botón" el cual redirige al usuario hacia la api de whatsapp para iniciar una conversación nueva.
La cuestión es más compleja, porque el número telefónico cambia dinámicamente según los datos almacenados en la base de datos de la web: el número que tiene menos "contactos", es al que se redirige mediante este botón.

A estos datos los guardo en una tabla, en un array que he codificado en JSON, quedando algo similar a esto:

```
[{"meta_id":13106,"post_id":1,"meta_key":"botondata","meta_value":
"[{\"nombre\":\"Asesor 1\",\"numero\":\"123456789\",\"clientes\":1},
{\"nombre\":\"Asesor 2\",\"numero\":\"987654321\",\"clientes\":2,}]
```

La idea inicial era utilizar javascript y ejecutar a la carga del DOM, una función que mediante la api fetch, obtenga estos datos, determine cuál 'Asesor' tiene menos clientes y entonces genere el link hacia este.
Acto seguido, agregarle un evento al click de la div que redireccione al usuario hacia el link generado, también con javascript.

Esto funciona perfectamente para mi navegador y para los de algunos cercanos que les he pedido que lo prueben, sin embargo se me hizo evidente que el tráfico común de la web no podía hacer uso de este botón porque no se ejecutaba el script.

Por ese motivo, pasé a realizar mediante php la consulta a la base de datos, determinar el Asesor con menos clientes, obtener su número, generar el link y, mediante PHP, renderizar un componente 'a' con un href que tiene el link (esto a modo de botón y estilizado como tal, claro), lo cual funciona correctamente.

El problema que tengo ahora y por el que consulto, es que necesito contabilizar cuando el usuario cliquea el botón, y es dirigido a la api que inicia la conversación, porque de esta manera se compensaría automáticamente la cantidad de clientes de cada Asesor.
La idea inicial nuevamente fue correr una función mediante javascript en el evento click del botón, que mediante fetch aumente en 1 el valor de 'clientes' del asesor correspondiente, y nuevamente funciona a la perfección para mi navegador y los cercanos, pero no para los usuarios comunes.

Dejo esquematizado el código a ver si ayuda en algo:

```
let numeroGlobal = document.getElementById("numero-cargado").dataset["numero"];
let botonData=[];
const handleClick = (e) => {
    if (e.target.id === "botonWspClick") {
        aumentaClick(numeroGlobal);
    }
};

const aumentaClick = (numero) => {
fetch("/endpoint.php", {
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
      Authorization: "*****",
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
      Function: "obtenerBoton",
    },
  })
    .then((res) => {
      if (res.ok) {
        return res.json();
      } else {
        throw new Error(res.statusText, { cause: res });
      }
    })
    .then((res) => {
      let indice = null;

      if (res['data'].length > 0) {
        if (res['data'][0].hasOwnProperty("meta_value")) {
          botonData = res['data'][0].meta_value;
          botonData = JSON.parse(botonData);
          botonData.forEach((el, i) => {
            if (el.numero == numero) {
              indice = i;
            }
          });
        }
      }

      botonData[indice].clicks++;
      botonData[indice].clicksAcumulados++;

      let cargaUtil = JSON.stringify({ data: JSON.stringify(botonData) });
      fetch("/endpoint.php", {
        method: "POST",
        body:cargaUtil,
        headers: {
          Authorization: "******",
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
          Function: "guardarBoton",
        },
      })
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log(err);
    });
    
};
document.addEventListener("click", handleClick);
```

Comment: Si es posible, pero yo creo que al día de hoy es extremadamente raro (puedo estar equivocado), es que sin javascript hoy no funciona la web, porque lo que creo que tu problema está en otro lado que no has detectado. De todas maneras, puedes hacer esa funcionalidad sin javascript, pones un link a un php, al servidor determinar el asesor menos ocupado y contabiliza lo que tengas que contabilizar y finalmente lo redirige donde tu quieras

Comment: Opino igual que @Yussef. Es más, no es que puedas hacer esa funcionalidad en php, sino que DEBES hacerla en el servidor, no puedes llevar la cuenta en el navegador del cliente ¿y si usa dos navegadores a la vez? llevarías dos cuentas independientes

Comment: Gracias por comentar. El flujo seria entonces un link a un archivo php que haga el proceso de consultar la bd y determinar el asesor con menos clientes, contabilizar el cliente y finalmente redirigir al usuario.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No es necesario tanta parafernelia, lo unico que ocupas es un boton que al darle click... te redirecciones a un archivo php, este archivo lo puede llamar `buscandor_agente.php` este se encarga de hacer el analisis y buscar el contacto que deseas en la base de datos, cuando tengas ese dato puedes desde el mismo archivo php hacer un redirecionamiento duro a la api de whatsapp:

para un numero telefonico de contacto: +39 34567879

```php
$time = 0; // tiempo que demora en hacer el redireccionado.
$contact = '3934567879'; //numero de contacto extraido de la base de datos.
header('refresh:' . $time . ';url=https://wa.me/' . $contact);
```

[Documentacion](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.header.php)

Otra opcion existente pero que no aconcejo usar, es hacer un echo de un redirecionamiento mediante codigo javascript, quedaria algo asi:

```php
echo '<script>window.open("https://wa.me/'.$contact.'", "_blank");</script>'
```

en esta opcion la api de whatsapp es llamada en una tab diferente, [Documentacion](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open).

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu aporte. Efectivamente implementé esta solución y de momento las cosas andan. No es tan perfecto, hoy por ejemplo tengo mas contactos que han llegado al whatsapp que los que ha logrado contabilizar, no se como es posible ya que el mismo archivo que redirige, contabiliza pero seguiré indagando ahora con esto!

Comment: elimina los duplicados XD

Comment: jajaja lo bueno es que no son duplicados!

Comment: ok, bueno eso ya se escapa de mis manos necesitaria mas contexto y que coloques todo lo nuevo en una pregunta